# Function steps work, but not when in lapply

Tags: r

I have a simple set of steps to reformat some data.  These steps work (Finding the differential and then isolating those above or below one standard devation).

```
x <- x[!is.na(x)]
x.d <- diff(x)
x.d <- x.d[!is.na(x.d)]
x.d <- ifelse(abs(x.d) > sd(x.d,na.rm = TRUE),x.d, 0)
```

I have a lot of series, and so want to put the lines into a function, and call with lapply.  e.g.

```
  data.prep <- function(x) {
  <The lines above>
  return(x.d) }
```

I attached the data and created a list with the series name(s) in it - "world" in this case and called the function

```
mydatalist <- as.list("world")
mydatalist.d <- lapply(mydatalist, FUN = data.prep)
```

and I get

```
 Error in abs(x.d) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function 
3. ifelse(abs(x.d) > sd(x.d, na.rm = TRUE), x.d, 0) at FdataPrep.R#5
2. FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1. lapply(mydatalist, FUN = data.prep)
```

This is a link to what I'm trying to get. 
[Input data versus wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDwnK.png)
The graph on the left is the raw data, the graph on the right is output I want.

Can somebody please help understand where I'm going wrong?

Thank you,

John

Comment: `mydatalist` is a list with a single element in it: the string `"world"`. When you pass that string through your `data.prep` function, it eventually tries to take an absolute value, which is not well-defined for strings.

Comment: Is `world` a different variable? What's the desired output here? Maybe you wanted `mydatalist <- list(world)`? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: "world" would be a data series in a vector, for example "world annual population" 50 numerical values.

Comment: I've added a link to the output of the working graph.  That shows the raw data and the desired output.

Comment: Just a clarification on what @MrFlick wrote: when you quote "world" you are passing it as a string not a variable. Try passing `world` not `"world"`.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the clarification. @MrFlick pointed me to **a** solution.  I pass the function a string as before, e.g. "world", but then use get() to grab the data.  Why I can't just pass the data series, I don't know - I tried many things, but they would all fail.  Thank you for all the help.